# user login simulator,js,validating the username&password,failed

Tags: javascript

used for validating the strings inputted.

no if conditions works in the js code but the else if one,asking for help.

html code:

```
<div>
    <h2 class="title">login</h2>
    <p>usernamehere：</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="login">
    <p>passwordhere：</p>
    <input type="password" name="userpassword" id="userpswd" placeholder="password">
    <button id="login">login</button>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

js code:

```
var userenter = $("#username").val()
var pswdenter = $("#userpswd").val()
$("#login").click(function(){
    if(userenter == "letsstart" && pswdenter == "start"){
        alert("pass");
    }
    else if(userenter == "" || pswdenter == ""){
        alert("enter please")
      }
    else{
        alert("invalid")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the `.val` of `username` and `password` inside the click handler instead of global . Otherwise it will have the document initial load value of the input . That's why each time you got empty input

```js
$("#login").click(function() {
  var userenter = $("#username").val()  //
  var pswdenter = $("#userpswd").val()  //
  console.log(userenter,pswdenter)
  if (userenter == "letsstart" && pswdenter == "start") {
    alert("pass");
  } else if (userenter == "" || pswdenter == "") {
    alert("enter please")
  } else {
    alert("invalid")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 class="title">login</h2>
  <p>usernamehere：</p>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="login">
  <p>passwordhere：</p>
  <input type="password" name="userpassword" id="userpswd" placeholder="password">
  <button id="login">login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving the values of `username` and `userpswd` once and then using it in the click handler. So your if statement is always looking at the values from the first time they were set (probably on page load).

You should move the value retrieval code inside you click handler.

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    var userenter = $("#username").val()
    var pswdenter = $("#userpswd").val()
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values of `#username` and `#userpswd` everytime you click on the "login" button. Otherwise, `userenter` and `pswdenter` will be empty when you will check if credentials are valid or not, because when you define them `#username` and `#userpswd` inputs are empty. I don't know if it's well explained, but here is the code :

```js
$("#login").click(function(){
    var userenter = $("#username").val()
    var pswdenter = $("#userpswd").val()
    
    if(userenter == "letsstart" && pswdenter == "start"){
        alert("pass");
    }
    else if(userenter == "" || pswdenter == ""){
        alert("enter please")
      }
    else{
        alert("invalid")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h2 class="title">login</h2>
    <p>usernamehere：</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="login">
    <p>passwordhere：</p>
    <input type="password" name="userpassword" id="userpswd" placeholder="password">
    <button id="login">login</button>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```